# Class 'Room' is abstract; cannot be instantiated

Tags: java, abstract-class, instantiation

I have an abstract class `Room` which has subclasses `Family` and `Standard`.

I have created `room = new ArrayList<Room>();` within a `Hostel` class and a method to add a room to the ArrayList;

```
public String addRoom(String roomNumber, boolean ensuite)
{
    if  (roomNumber.equals("")) 
        return "Error - Empty name field\n";
    else
    
    room.add( new Room(roomNumber,ensuite) );
    return  "RoomNumber: " + roomNumber + " Ensuite: " + ensuite 
     + "  Has been added to Hostel " + hostelName;
}
```

However I get the following compile time error;

> Room is abstract; cannot be instantiated

I understand that abstract classes cannot be instantiated, but what is the best way to add a room?

Comment: You say you "have an abstract class `Room`", and you're asking why the compiler complains when you try to instantiate it?

Comment: I think you should have a quick glance at this page: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/ :-)

Comment: Why did you you made room abstract? Ask yourself if you really understand what `abstract` does and you should be able to answer the question yourself.

Comment: where you are giving this method declaration?

Comment: You cannot create instance of `abstract` class, the concrete class is needed. For example: `room.add( new BigRoom(roomNumber,ensuite) );`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You have this error because you are trying to create an instance of abstract class, which is impossible. You have to

```
room.add(new Family(roomNumber, ensuoute));
```

or

```
room.add(new Standard(roomNumber, ensuoute));
```

Comment: thanks, this is exactly what i was looking for, duno how i didnt think of it

Answer (score 8):

The error says it all: `Room` is an abstract class, and abstract classes cannot be instantiated.

You're trying to instantiate `Room` here:

```
new Room(roomNumber,ensuite)
```

You can only create instances of concrete (i.e. non-abstract) classes. It is likely to be the case that `Family` and `Standard` are concrete classes and can therefore be instantiated.

To fix this, you'll need to figure out the correct room type given the room number, and instantiate the appropriate class.

Answer (score -1):

You are creating an instance of an abstract class;

```
room.add(new Room(roomNumber,ensuite));
```

This is not correct.

Comment: This doesn't add anything new to the question and could be deleted.