# Android Editable is abstract; cannot be instantiated

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, spannablestringbuilder, android-editable

I'm creating an `EditText` subclass and I want to make an Editable variable to pass to the super class.

When I originally tried

```
private Editable unicodeText = new Editable();
```

I got the error

> 'Editable' is abstract; cannot be instantiated

Searching for this error in Google did not return any helpful results, so now that I have found the answer I am adding this question with an answer below.

Comment: This wasn't a helpful result?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8519943/class-room-is-abstract-cannot-be-instantiated

Comment: @cricket_007, My question was more about how to make an `Editable` object and not just the "can't instantiate something abstract" problem.  [Android How can I Convert a String to a Editable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13352531/android-how-can-i-convert-a-string-to-a-editable) was an appropriately marked duplicate.

Comment: Your question didn't include your ultimate goal -- it just listed an error about you trying to instantiate abstract class, an error for which there are plenty of answers already. It's not feasable or helpful to have a separate question for instantiating every subclass of an abstract class out there. If your question was "what's a good subclass for wrapping a String into an Editable," you should have asked that... though it'd probably be off topic as a request for an external resource.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Editable`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Editable.html) is an interface, not a class, and as such cannot be instantiated.

> Interfaces cannot be instantiated—they can only be implemented by classes or extended by other interfaces. ([docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/createinterface.html))

However, the class [`SpannableStringBuilder`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/SpannableStringBuilder.html) implements `Editable` so you can do the following:

```
private Editable unicodeText = new SpannableStringBuilder();
```

Thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13352598/3681880) for setting me on the right track.